# Sorting a list by first finding the field to sort on within in the list

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

This one seems difficult and would appreciate any help or assistance that one might be able to give.

I have a list, List. Each Car object has a list, List. I would like to sort my Car list by 1 of those Accessories. In my example, I am guaranteed to have several Car objects with the accessory I'm trying to find.

Now I know the accessory name, but I don't know the syntax to use to sort my Car list on the accessory name.

- AccessoryObj1 => Name (String: Dynamic Steering)
- AccessoryObj2 => Name (String: Side Assist)
- Car1  -> List (AccessoryObj1, AccessoryObj2, AccessoryObj3)
- Car2  -> List (AccessoryObj1, AccessoryObj2,
  AccessoryObj3)

List (Car1, Car2)

The syntax I tried was the following:

```
String sortField = "Side Assist";
List<Car> sortedList = sortedList.OrderBy(
                        x => x.Accessories.OfType<Accessory>().ToList().First(y => y.Name == sortField)).ToList();
```

I am attempting to OrderBy (Ascending) my List of Cars by referencing the Accessories list of each Car object, and taking the First match where an Accessory object's name, within the Accessories list, matches the sortField value.

Unfortunately this attempt results in the following error:

> At least one object must implement IComparable

I hope my problem is clear enough and thanks in advance.

---

Thanks for the solution provided by user2399170, I'm 3/4 the way there: Taking their solution/sample, I'm now trying have the end result ordered Ascending/Descending. Here's the code adjusted:

```
public class Accessory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Accessory> Accessories { get; set; }
}

private IEnumerable<Car> GetCars()
    {
        var cars = new List<Car>();
        cars.Add(
            new Car()
            {
                Name = "CAR1",
                Accessories = new List<Accessory>()
                {
                    new Accessory() { Name = "ABS Brakes", Value = "1" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Airbag", Value = "1" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Climate Control", Value = "1" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Heated Seats", Value = "1" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "HID Xenon Headlights", Value = "1" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Radio", Value = "1" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Quattro", Value = "0" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Sat/Nav", Value = "1" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Side Assist", Value = "0" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Name", Value = "BMW" },
                }
            });
        cars.Add(
            new Car()
            {
                Name = "CAR2",
                Accessories = new List<Accessory>()
                {
                    new Accessory() { Name = "ABS Brakes", Value = "1" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Airbag", Value = "1" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Climate Control", Value = "1" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Heated Seats", Value = "0" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "HID Xenon Headlights", Value = "0" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Radio", Value = "1" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Quattro", Value = "0" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Sat/Nav", Value = "0" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Side Assist", Value = "0" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Name", Value = "Mazda" },
                }
            });
        cars.Add(
            new Car()
            {
                Name = "CAR3",
                Accessories = new List<Accessory>()
                {
                    new Accessory() { Name = "ABS Brakes", Value = "1" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Airbag", Value = "1" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Climate Control", Value = "1" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Heated Seats", Value = "1" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "HID Xenon Headlights", Value = "1" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Radio", Value = "1" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Quattro", Value = "1" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Sat/Nav", Value = "1" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Side Assist", Value = "1" },
                    new Accessory() { Name = "Name", Value = "Audi" },

                }
            });

        String[] sortRules = new string[] { "Name" };

        List<Car> sortedCars = sortRules
            .SelectMany(sortRule => cars.Where(car => car.Accessories.Any(acc => acc.Name == sortRule)))
            .Distinct().ToList();

        return sortedCars;
    }
```

I'd like to sort the end result by the value of the sort field 'Name' which would be in this example, "Audi", "BMW", "Mazda"

How this all works is, the user can select from a Drop Down 'Name' and the result can be sorted by the value for 'Name.' Unfortunately, this is how the data is returned by a third party source which I cannot control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sample

```
private static IEnumerable<Car> GetCars(string filterByAccessory, bool sortAscending = true)
{
    var cars = new List<Car>();
    cars.Add(
        new Car()
        {
            Name = "CAR1",
            Accessories = new List<Accessory>()
        {
            new Accessory() { Name = "ABS Brakes", Value = "1" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Airbag", Value = "1" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Climate Control", Value = "1" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Heated Seats", Value = "1" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "HID Xenon Headlights", Value = "1" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Radio", Value = "1" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Quattro", Value = "0" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Sat/Nav", Value = "1" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Side Assist", Value = "0" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Name", Value = "BMW" },
        }
        });
    cars.Add(
        new Car()
        {
            Name = "CAR2",
            Accessories = new List<Accessory>()
        {
            new Accessory() { Name = "ABS Brakes", Value = "1" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Airbag", Value = "1" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Climate Control", Value = "1" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Heated Seats", Value = "0" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "HID Xenon Headlights", Value = "0" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Radio", Value = "1" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Quattro", Value = "0" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Sat/Nav", Value = "0" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Side Assist", Value = "0" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Name", Value = "Mazda" },
        }
        });
    cars.Add(
        new Car()
        {
            Name = "CAR3",
            Accessories = new List<Accessory>()
        {
            new Accessory() { Name = "ABS Brakes", Value = "1" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Airbag", Value = "1" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Climate Control", Value = "1" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Heated Seats", Value = "1" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "HID Xenon Headlights", Value = "1" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Radio", Value = "1" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Quattro", Value = "1" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Sat/Nav", Value = "1" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Side Assist", Value = "1" },
            new Accessory() { Name = "Name", Value = "Audi" },

        }
        });

    var filteredCars = cars.Where(c => c.Accessories.Any(a => a.Name == filterByAccessory));

    var sortedCars = sortAscending
        ? filteredCars.OrderBy(x => x.Accessories.First(a => a.Name == filterByAccessory).Value)
        : filteredCars.OrderByDescending(x => x.Accessories.First(a => a.Name == filterByAccessory).Value);

    return sortedCars;
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you! I have used it and will be implementing into my project as soon as possible. 2 questions if you don't mind: 1. sortRules: Why more than 1? Is that so you can sort on multiple fields at once? For my application I would only be using 1. 2. I would like to sort by Ascending or Descending using the sortField, for example in your sample, I would sort by Airbag. The real implementation requires this functionality, unfortunately this requirement does not make sense for the car example.

Comment: Updated original question with further explanation.

Comment: 1. SortRules - actually would be better to call it as sortRule, because it is really one rule that defines the order for searching accessories of car.I thought that you need something complex as this sample. If you

Comment: I added new sample, please check it

Comment: Thank you! This solution is exactly what I needed. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me. Hope 1 day I can return the favor with 1 of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

To sort by `Accessory` you need to make sure that class implements the `IComparable` interface

```
public class Accessory : IComparible
{
    public int CompareTo(object obj) {
        //Return 0 for equals
        //Return -1 if this object precedes the given object
        //Return 1 if this object follows the given object
    }
}
```